# How to interpolate between two curves to get a data map in python

Tags: python, interpolation

I have two curves of measured data with a variable.

[image: Figure 1]

The data is the following:

```
y_min = np.array([80.4, 82.1, 84])
y_max = np.array([149.5, 169.3, 197.4])
variable_data = np.array([14.1, 1.9])
x_data = np.array([157.0, 235.0, 314.0])
```

Can I interpolate between the curves to get a y-value by defining a the x-value and the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Check out numpys linear interpolation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html

Small sample code to get started:

```
import numpy as np

y_min = np.array([80.4, 82.1, 84])
y_max = np.array([149.5, 169.3, 197.4])
variable_data = np.array([14.1, 1.9])
x_data = np.array([157.0, 235.0, 314.0])

vari = 14.1
inter_point = 160

if vari == 14.1:
    x_i = np.interp(inter_point, x_data, y_max)
elif vari == 1.9:
    x_i = np.interp(inter_point, x_data, y_min)
else:
    print("No data for point:", vari)
    x_i = "NaN"

print("Interpolated value:", x_i)
```